# How to get a unique POSIX message queue?

Tags: posix, message-queue

I'm working on a simple parallel application in which I want to use a single process to maintain status information about a family of worker processes.  It seems relatively easy to set up a POSIX message queue in which all of the worker bees can send periodic updates to the status maintainer.  My problem?  A POSIX message queue has to have a name.  I don't want to pick a name; all I care about is getting a unique message queue, much as I would using SYSV message queues with `IPC_PRIVATE`.  For a unique *filename* I could use `mkstemp(3)` or for a unique open file descriptor I could use `tmpfile(3)`.  **How should I get a unique POSIX message queue?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to pick a name; all I care about is getting a unique message queue, much as I would using SYSV message queues with IPC_PRIVATE

Well, with POSIX message queues, you *do* have to specify a name, but you don't have to preserve it nor allow others to use the same queue by that name.

**IPC_PRIVATE mimicry**

Do what `mkstemp` and `tmpfile` do under the hood.  Borrow any of the "tmp"/"temp" name selection algorithms to generate something "/reasonably_unique", `mq_open` it O_CREAT|O_EXCL, and then `mq_unlink` it.  Child worker processes can then inherit the message queue descriptor.

Caveat:  Could root or your EUID gone rogue figure out what you're doing and jump in between the `mq_open` and the `mq_unlink`?  Yes.

**Alternative implementation**

Alternatively, use a SOCK_DGRAM `socketpair` or `pipe` instead.  Those offer similar semantics to POSIX message queues — `attr.mq_msgsize` becomes SO_SNDBUF/SO_RCVBUF or an agreement to respect PIPE_BUF, `mq_notify` becomes I/O selectability (probably already the case) — though you do lose message prioritization.